# catchall URL regex except specific page

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

We have an old URL structure in circulation in some email signatures and I'd like to create a regex pattern to do permanent redirects with the exception of a specific page.

Each office location we used to have a sub-domain. For example, Office 1 was office1.domain.com and Office 2 was office2.domain.com and so on through to Office 16.

Staff in each office had an email signature with a link to an Email Disclaimer page on their specific sub-domain site.  Eg. office1.domain.com/email_disclaimer.

When our new website launched, we got rid of this old structure and now just have the one website with pages for each office instead of sub-domains for each office (eg. domain.com/office1).  So I am currently using 16 regex rules such as `^/office1.*` to redirect any page from the old office1.domain.com to the static domain.com/office1.  But this also redirects the email disclaimer.

How do I modify the regex to exclude "email_disclaimer" from the * catchall so that it redirects everything except, for example, office1.domain.com/email_disclaimer?

If this can be done, would I then create a rule that matches "any" subdomain for domain.com/email_disclaimer and redirects it to the new static email disclaimer page?  How would this regex rule look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead

```
^(?!.*email_disclaimer)office1
```

[image]

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/6bP1A1/1/)